# Can I send variables via form action?

Tags: php

I need the action from button click to receive and send the variables to check the SQL language in another page. I don't need a href type to send. Can I send via action like these?

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="alreport.php?dateal=<?php echo $datereportal_newformat?>">
<input type="text" name="AlcoholDate" id="datepicker" />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button2" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You can. But instead of asking, you should have tried first.

Comment: The params sent in the query string will result in `$_GET['dateal']` while your form is otherwise ending up in `$_POST`, but yes, you can do this.

Comment: Yes, you can use query strings in form actions. You can mix GET query vars with a form that does POST. the action is just a url, after all, and normal url rules apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use input type hidden with echo to do what

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

```
<form action="/somewhere">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $var ?>" name="hiddenfield">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use input and set type to hidden

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="alreport.php">
<input type="hidden" name="dateal" value="<?= $datereportal_newformat; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="AlcoholDate" id="datepicker" />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button2" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your variable using:

```
<?php echo $_GET["dateal"] ?>
```